# How to change the text of links in active-admin dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

As the following image,

These links' text are generated by default.

For example.

I want to change the text 'Admin User' with 'Administrator' or '管理者'

How to do it ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: your question is not clear?

Comment: @Shailendrsingh Hi I updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your admin/admin_user.rb file

add this line for customize menu label:

```
menu :label => "Administrator"
```

So It will be look like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
    menu :label => "Administrator"
end
```

If you want to translate label as per your specific language then add locale and use it here.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
    menu :label => proc{ I18n.t("administrator") }
end
```

You can check more [here.](http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#customize_the_menu)